GASで共有ドライブ配下の全てのSpreadsheetから特定IDを利用しているSpreadsheetを抽出して出力したい
マスターとして管理しているSpreadsheetのキーが変更になったため、利用しているSpreadsheetを呼び出し、旧キーと新キーを入れ替えたいんです。
入替えは手動で処理しても良いのですが、作成シートが多くなりどのシートで参照しているかが分からないので
検索したいのです。（作成者も異なるので管理出来ていません）
